# LabVIEW data writing in a TDMS file

Tags: excel, labview, data-acquisition, daq-mx

I want to acquire pressure data from a pressure sensor. When I write the data using the "write to measurement file", only one part of the data is saved and others are missed.
I also try exporting data to excel from the waveform chart. But I receive a message that says there is not enough memory.
What should I do to save whole the data without missing them?
Is there any way to save the data directly to the Hard drive?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the expressVIs myself.  Recording directly to a TDMS file is the way to go. There are great examples of writing to a tdms file in the Labview examples.  I think the TDMS API is pretty intuitive as well, look at the TDMS palette under the File IO palette, all you really need for this is to open, write, then close.

TDMS are incredibly fast for writing to and allow multiple groupings and metadata at multiple levels.  I use TDMS all the time in my applications and never miss any data.